# Docker-compose with nginx templates to pass global variables. Adding a command to my compose breaks this function

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

(Similar to an unanswered post from yesterday but I've since zoomed in on the cause of my issue so re-posting here with less text and deleting yesterdays post)

With the nginx image one can pass global env variables. [Documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx). On the link there's a section 'Using environment variables in nginx configuration (new in 1.19)'.
When running this container the functionality described above about global variables does indeed work as expected.

If I exec into the running container I see a script at the root level of the directory system `docker-entrypoint.sh`. From research it sounds like the method nginx docker uses to pass global variables relies on this script being run when the container starts and that this is an automatic process.

The trouble is, my docker-compose has a command `command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"`. When I include this command and run, it breaks the functionality with global variables. From doing some searching, adding a command breaks any entry point scripts? It seems I can only make use of the global variable functionality if I don't add any commands to my docker-compose since it stops docker-entrypoint.sh from being run.

Is there a 'right' way around this?

Works - global variables are passed through to nginx:

```
version: "3.5"
networks:
  collabora:

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    depends_on:
      - certbot   
      - collabora 
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx/templates:/etc/nginx/templates
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    env_file: .env
    networks:
      - collabora
```

Does not work, global variables are not passed through and the default.conf template is all that I get:

```
version: "3.5"
networks:
  collabora:

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    depends_on:
      - certbot   
      - collabora 
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx/templates:/etc/nginx/templates
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    env_file: .env
    command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"
    networks:
      - collabora
```

Comment: Can you delete the `command:`, and manually restart the container when you need to?  Or use a cron job on the host to restart it, if it needs to restart on a schedule?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the [entrypoint script](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/master/entrypoint/docker-entrypoint.sh#L12) inside the container, specifically the `if` statement that guards most of the code:

```
if [ "$1" = "nginx" -o "$1" = "nginx-debug" ]; then
   ...
fi
```

The templating and other entrypoint scripts will only run when `$1` is `nginx` or `nginx-debug`. That's not true for your Dockefile, in which `$1` would be `/bin/sh`.

The simplest option would be to replace the entrypoint script with a modified version that runs the entrypoint scripts unconditionally.  There are a couple ways of doing that, but the easiest is probably:

- Create a custom `docker-entrypoint.sh` script in your local directory (make sure it's executable).
- Mount that on top of the stock version in your `docker-compose.yml`:

  ```
  version: "3.5"
  networks:
    collabora:

  services:
    nginx:
      image: nginx
      depends_on:
        - certbot
        - collabora
      volumes:
        # Here is where we orverride the entrypoint script.
        - ./data/docker-entrypoint.sh:/docker-entrypoint.sh
        - ./data/nginx/templates:/etc/nginx/templates
        - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
        - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
      ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
      env_file: .env
      command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"
      networks:
        - collabora
  ```

---

Removing the guard `if` statement gives us:

```
#!/bin/sh
# vim:sw=4:ts=4:et

set -e

if [ -z "${NGINX_ENTRYPOINT_QUIET_LOGS:-}" ]; then
    exec 3>&1
else
    exec 3>/dev/null
fi

if /usr/bin/find "/docker-entrypoint.d/" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -print -quit 2>/dev/null | read v; then
    echo >&3 "$0: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration"

    echo >&3 "$0: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/"
    find "/docker-entrypoint.d/" -follow -type f -print | sort -V | while read -r f; do
        case "$f" in
            *.sh)
                if [ -x "$f" ]; then
                    echo >&3 "$0: Launching $f";
                    "$f"
                else
                    # warn on shell scripts without exec bit
                    echo >&3 "$0: Ignoring $f, not executable";
                fi
                ;;
            *) echo >&3 "$0: Ignoring $f";;
        esac
    done

    echo >&3 "$0: Configuration complete; ready for start up"
else
    echo >&3 "$0: No files found in /docker-entrypoint.d/, skipping configuration"
fi

exec "$@"
```

Comment: I don't fully understand everything here but are you saying I just need to copy the existing `docker-entrypoint.sh` to my directory and then create a volume with it as part of my compose? OK, I'll try that now

Comment: ...making sure to modify it, of course, to remove that if statement. And please let me know if you'd like me to clarify something in this answer.

Comment: That if statement seems to be pretty much the whole script no? I'm confused! Would you be able to share exactly what the new modified `docker-entrypoint.sh` should look like?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show the modified script.

Comment: This does indeed work, sincere thanks I doubt I would have been able to figure that out on my own.

Comment: May I run another potential solution by you? Someone suggested adding a script into the container at `docker-entrypoint.d` and then I would not have to manually adjust the `docker-entrypoint.sh` script above. I tried this, I added the command part of my docker-compose up above (`/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait...`) into a file `test.sh` and then under volumes `/test.sh:/docker-entrypoint.d/test.sh`. This 'almost' works. The service runs and in the container `/etc/nginx/conf.d` contains a correctly transformed app.conf file with my global vars swapped in but ...

Comment: ...  but, the trouble is the default.conf is still there and seems to over ride the app.conf. I tried changing my template from `app.conf.template` to `default.conf.template` and this does work in that only `default.conf` appears in the container under `/etc/nginx/conf.d` and it also has the correct configuration, but does not work - my redirects do not work as before. Seems it must be an `app.conf` file in this case in order to function. Any ideas?

Comment: Slightly on a tangent but getting this to work was troublesome. But as of 1.19, the image does handle running the function by itself. I was troubleshooting my own implementation (which is built and deployed separately via Jenkins with two .YML) fortunately even with some docker compose or docker stack deploy options or pointing to a custom YML, I did not run into the issues as the question parent author on needing to have the custom entrypoint. But this was an excellent answer and helped indirectly.

Comment: @DougFir you might want to open a new question for the issue you're asking about; comments aren't really a great place for this. If you want to leave the URL to the new question here in the comments I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: @larsks I've posted a very similar question to the one above over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66756771/add-a-file-to-docker-entrypoint-d-as-part-of-a-app-conf-template-file-to-swa). If you have any ideas it would be most welcome. I like the idea of adding shell files to entrypoint.d as opposed to editing `docker-entrypoint.sh` script