# Add a file to `/docker-entrypoint.d/` as part of a app.conf.template file to swap global variables into nginx set up

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I would like to pass global variables to my nginx app.conf via a app.conf.template file using docker and docker-compose.

When using an app.conf.template file with no commands in `docker-compose.yaml` my variables translate successfully and my redirects via nginx work as expected. But when I use a command in docker-compose my nginx and redirects fail.

My set up is per the instructions on [the documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/), under section 'Using environment variables in nginx configuration (new in 1.19)':

> Out-of-the-box, nginx doesn't support environment variables inside
> most configuration blocks. But this image has a function, which will
> extract environment variables before nginx starts.
>
> Here is an example using docker-compose.yml:
>
> web:   image: nginx   volumes:
>
> - ./templates:/etc/nginx/templates   ports:
> - "8080:80"   environment:
> - NGINX_HOST=foobar.com
> - NGINX_PORT=80
>
> By default, this function reads template files in
> /etc/nginx/templates/*.template and outputs the result of executing
> envsubst to /etc/nginx/conf.d
> ... more ...

My docker-compose.yaml works when it looks like this:

```
version: "3.5"
networks:
  collabora:
  
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    depends_on:
      - certbot   
      - collabora 
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx/templates:/etc/nginx/templates
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    env_file: .env
    networks:
      - collabora
```

On host I have a conf file `./data/nginx/templates/app.conf.template` which contains a conf file with global variables throughout in the form `${variable_name}`.

With this set up I'm able to run the container and my redirects work as expected. When I `exec` into the container I can `cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf` and see the file with the correct variables swapped in from the .env file.

But I need to add a command to my docker-compose.yaml:

```
command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"
```

When I add that command the set up fails and the global variables are not swapped into the app.conf file within the container.

On another forum it was suggested I move the `command` into it's own file in the container. I then gave this a try and created a shell script `test.sh`:

```
#/bin/sh 

while :; 
    do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; 
    nginx -s reload; 
done;
```

My new docker-compose:

```
version: "3.5"
networks:
  collabora:
  
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    depends_on:
      - certbot   
      - collabora 
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx/templates:/etc/nginx/templates
      - ./test.sh:/docker-entrypoint.d/test.sh # new - added test.sh into the container here
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    env_file: .env
    networks:
      - collabora
```

This fails. Although when I exec into the container and `cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf` I DO see the correct config, it just does not seem to be working in that my redirects, which otherwise do work when I don't include this test.sh script within `/docker-entrypoint.d/`.

I [asked nearly same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66732240/docker-compose-with-nginx-templates-to-pass-global-variables-adding-a-command-t) yesterday and was given a working solution. However, it 'feels more correct' to add a shell script to the container at `/docker-entrypoint.d/` and go that route instead like I've attempted in this post.

Comment: What are the logs of the container? What is your purpose? To reload nginx config every 6h? As nothing is going to change the config in the container, would have no effect...

Comment: The thing is that your tes.sht script never ends, so the CMD of the image is never executed.

Comment: Hi @zigarn here's a line from the logs of the container, this line repeats over and over `2021/03/23 01:30:25 [emerg] 42590#42590: host not found in upstream "collabora" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:30
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "collabora" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:30`. The script is copied from [this](https://pentacent.medium.com/nginx-and-lets-encrypt-with-docker-in-less-than-5-minutes-b4b8a60d3a71) blog post "In the nginx section, you need to make sure that nginx reloads the newly obtained certificates" ...

Comment: ... `command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"` Which then says "This makes nginx reload its configuration (and certificates) every six hours in the background and launches nginx in the foreground."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For what you're trying to do, I think the best solution is to create a sidecar container, like this:

```
version: "3.5"

networks:
  collabora:

volumes:
  shared_run:

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19
    volumes:
      - "shared_run:/run"
      - ./data/nginx/templates:/etc/nginx/templates
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    env_file: .env
    networks:
      - collabora

  nginx_reloader:
    image: nginx:1.19
    pid: service:nginx
    volumes:
      - "shared_run:/run"
    entrypoint:
      - /bin/bash
      - -c
    command:
      - |
        while :; do
          sleep 60
          echo reloading
          nginx -s reload
        done
```

This lets you use the upstream `nginx` image without needing to muck about with its mechanics. The key here is that (a) we run the `nginx_reloader` container in the same PID namespace as the `nginx` container itself, and (b) we arrange for the two containers to share a `/run` directory so that the `nginx -s reload` command can find the pid of the `nginx` process in the expected location.

Comment: This works. Thank you again!. Just to understand, if you have a moment I'd really like to understand this... 1. what is `shared_run` volume doing? Is that a volume between two containers as opposed to between host and container? Why do we need it? What's stored there? 2. What does the entry point on nginx_reloader do?

Comment: 1. The `shared_run` volume is mounted at `/run` in both containers, so when `nginx` creates `/run/nginx.pid` in the main container it is also visible in the reloader container. 2. The entrypoint in the reloader container lets us pass in a shell script as a verbatim argument in the `command`.